# Differences between MPI_Scatter and MPI_Bcast

Tags: c++, mpi

Can anyone please explain what are the differences between `MPI_Scatter` and `MPI_Bcast`? (Beside the fact that any process can broadcast using `MPI_Scatter` and only root can use `MPI_Bcast`)

In which cases I should use the first one over the other?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`MPI_Bcast()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Bcast.html) sends the same piece of data to everyone, while [`MPI_Scatter()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Scatter.html) sends each process a part of the input array. `MPI_Bcast()` is the opposite of `MPI_Reduce()` and `MPI_Scatter()` is the opposite of `MPI_Gather()`. A little scheme like [this one](http://mpitutorial.com/mpi-scatter-gather-and-allgather/) is self-explanatory.

And both `MPI_Scatter()` and `MPI_Bcast()` have an argument named `int root` to specify the root process.

Comment: While `MPI_SCATTER` is indeed the opposite of `MPI_GATHER`, I wouldn't call `MPI_BCAST` the opposite of `MPI_REDUCE`.

Comment: Right, `MPI_Reduce()` can combine the pieces of data in many different [ways](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node78.html), such as `MPI_SUM` or `MPI_MAX` and `MPI_Bcast()` provides the same piece of data to every process, without any operation on the way.

Answer (score 15):

MPI_Bcast takes a single data element at the root process (the red box) and copies it to all other processes. MPI_Scatter takes an array of elements and distributes the elements in the order of process rank.

[image: the illustration,]